# How much overhead do function calls have in Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am puzzled by the cost of a function call, which seems to be completely unreasonable to me, and makes me think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Consider the following Haskell code:

```
module Main where
logistic x = 4.0*x*(1.0-x)

lg :: Double -> Int -> Double
lg !x 0 = x
lg !x !n = lg (logistic x) (n-1)

main = putStrLn $ show $ lg 0.7861 100000000
```

Compiling this with the command

```
 ghc -O3 -XBangPatterns -o tsths tst.hs
```

and running it, I get:

```
real    0m15.904s
user    0m15.853s
sys     0m0.016s
```

If instead of calling the function `logistic` I calculate the expression inline:

```
module Main where

lg :: Double -> Int -> Double
lg !x 0 = x
lg !x !n = lg (4.0*x*(1.0-x)) (n-1)

main = putStrLn $ show $ lg 0.7861 100000000
```

the execution time becomes:

```
real    0m0.838s
user    0m0.828s
sys     0m0.004s
```

which is exactly the same as the equivalent C program, which is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int i, num=100000000;
   double x=0.7861;
   for (i=0; i<num; ++i)
      x *= 4.0*(1.0-x);
   printf("%lg\n", x);
}
```

Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with GHC 6.12.1 on Linux/x86-64; 0.42s for both programs.

Comment: By the way, `-O3` doesn't really exist for GHC. In recent versions, that gives you `-O2`, in older versions, no optimisation at all.

Comment: You should report this as a ghc bug.  It should have optimized the version without a type signature much better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a type signature to `logistic` and you will see the speedup. Allow me to use CPP to demonstrate the difference.

```
bash> cat tst.hs
module Main where

#if defined(SIG)
logistic :: Double -> Double
#endif
logistic x = 4.0*x*(1.0-x)

lg :: Double -> Int -> Double
lg !x 0 = x
lg !x !n = lg (logistic x) (n-1)

main = putStrLn $ show $ lg 0.7861 100000000


bash> ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
```

If compiled without SIG defined (the type signature is excluded):

```
bash> ghc -O3 -XBangPatterns -XCPP -o tsths tst.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tst.hs, tst.o )
Linking tsths ...


bash> time ./tsths
0.34209286442469333

real    0m13.187s
user    0m13.177s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Now lets compile with SIG defined so the signature is included:

```
bash> rm tsths *.o *.hi


bash> ghc -O3 -XBangPatterns -XCPP -DSIG -o tsths tst.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tst.hs, tst.o )
Linking tsths ...
bash> time ./tsths
0.34209286442469333

real    0m0.464s
user    0m0.440s
sys 0m0.020s
```

Not sure why GHC doesn't optimize it without the signature; the monomorphism restriction should restrict it to `Double -> Double` anyways.

Comment: Did you get a different timing before making that change?

Comment: Yes, I got the long time (~13s) without the type signature.

Comment: That's strange. Which GHC version?

Comment: Yes! That worked, many thanks. Surprising that this is not optimized away, as you say, and that the price for unboxing is so high; but this will teach me to put the signatures before functions, which is a good idea anyway.

Comment: BTW, `logistic` is bound by a function binding, so the MR doesn't apply. However, GHC produces a specialised version (GHC >= 6.12.3 tested).

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm using GHC 7.4.1

Comment: @user1654556 It's obviously a bug in 7.4.1. I will post a bit that illustrates what happens soon. It's quite bad, actually. I **very very** strongly recommend upgrading to 7.4.2.

Comment: I'm using 7.4.1 as well --- it is what is offered on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @user1654556 I don't think unboxing has anything to do with the slowdown here.

Answer (score 21):

It's a bug in GHC-7.4.1. Looking at the generated core (only the core for the function `lg` is important, from GHC-7.4.2, we get

```
Main.lg3 :: GHC.Types.Double
[GblId,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 30 0}]
Main.lg3 = GHC.Float.$w$cfromRational Main.lg4 Main.lg2

Main.lg1 :: GHC.Types.Double
[GblId,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=False,
         ConLike=False, Cheap=False, Expandable=False,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 30 0}]
Main.lg1 = GHC.Float.$w$cfromRational Main.lg2 Main.lg2

Main.$wlg :: GHC.Prim.Double# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Double#
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Str=DmdType LL,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=2, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [0 30] 158 0}]
Main.$wlg =
  \ (ww_s1Oy :: GHC.Prim.Double#) (ww1_s1OC :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww1_s1OC of ds_Xvs {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case Main.lg3 of _ { GHC.Types.D# x_awJ ->
        case Main.lg1 of _ { GHC.Types.D# x1_awV ->
        letrec {
          $wlg1_X1PF [Occ=LoopBreaker]
            :: GHC.Prim.Double# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Double#
          [LclId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType LL]
          $wlg1_X1PF =
            \ (ww2_X1Pv :: GHC.Prim.Double#) (ww3_X1PA :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
              case ww3_X1PA of ds1_Xwr {
                __DEFAULT ->
                  $wlg1_X1PF
                    (GHC.Prim.*##
                       (GHC.Prim.*## x_awJ ww2_X1Pv) (GHC.Prim.-## x1_awV ww2_X1Pv))
                    (GHC.Prim.-# ds1_Xwr 1);
                0 -> ww2_X1Pv
              }; } in
        $wlg1_X1PF
          (GHC.Prim.*##
             (GHC.Prim.*## x_awJ ww_s1Oy) (GHC.Prim.-## x1_awV ww_s1Oy))
          (GHC.Prim.-# ds_Xvs 1)
        }
        };
      0 -> ww_s1Oy
    }
```

two top-level `Double`s and a decent loop.

GHC-7.4.1 was a bit too inlining-happy, that produced

```
Rec {
Main.$wlg [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Double# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Double#
[GblId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType LL]
Main.$wlg =
  \ (ww_s1NS :: GHC.Prim.Double#) (ww1_s1NW :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww1_s1NW of ds_Xvb {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Float.$wfromRat'' (-1021) 53 Main.logistic4 Main.logistic2
        of ww2_a1Mt { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Float.$wfromRat'' (-1021) 53 Main.logistic2 Main.logistic2
        of ww3_X1Nq { __DEFAULT ->
        Main.$wlg
          (GHC.Prim.*##
             (GHC.Prim.*## ww2_a1Mt ww_s1NS) (GHC.Prim.-## ww3_X1Nq ww_s1NS))
          (GHC.Prim.-# ds_Xvb 1)
        }
        };
      0 -> ww_s1NS
    }
end Rec }
```

and gave you two calls to the `fromRational` worker in each iteration.

Now, `fromRational` is a fairly complicated function. It is still rather slow, despite having gotten a much faster implementation in the 7.2 series, so these calls hurt big time.

With a type signature, there are no `Rational` top-level constants produced, only `Double` constants, and these are then used, which of course doesn't include a gratuitous slowdown.

Answer (score 11):

As suggested by Dan Burton it is actually overhead of polymorphic function, because GHC infers type `logistic :: Fractional a => a -> a`. If you specify type explicitly you generally enable both better checking and better optimizations. I believe it is good practice to specify type of function explicitly.

If you want to have function with polymorphic type but have full speed of monomorphic call in case of specific usage you can use `SPECIALIZE` pragma, but I believe this is GHC specific.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
logistic :: Fractional a => a -> a
{-# SPECIALISE logistic :: Double -> Double #-}
logistic x = 4.0*x*(1.0-x)

lg :: Double -> Int -> Double
lg !x 0 = x
lg !x !n = lg (logistic x) (n-1)

main = putStrLn $ show $ lg 0.7861 100000000
```

Also note that you can specify `LANGUAGE` pragma at the beginning of file to enable bang patterns and don't need to enable them on command line.

Times on my machine were 21 seconds for original, 0.67 sec for explicit type, 0.7 sec for specialize (which is basically the same).

I believe overhead of specialized call is very small because it is just bunch of instructions which gets inlined anyway but polymorphic function results in call. Though it is weird that GHC cant inline despite polymorphism.